# WEKA - Classification - Training and Test Set

Tags: classification, weka

I am performing a classification problem using 3 different classifiers namely, Decision Tree, Naive Bayes and IBK. I have two data sets which are the same in layout and attribute names but the values in each are different.

```
Training Set Example;
State
Population  
HouseholdIncome 
FamilyIncome    
perCapInc   
NumUnderPov 
EducationLevel_1    
EducationLevel_2    
EducationLevel_3    
UnemploymentRate    
EmployedRate    
ViolentCrimesPerPop 
Crime 
Rate

8, 0.19, 0.37, 0.39, 0.4, 0.08, 0.1, 0.18, 0.48, 0.27 ,0.68 ,0.2 ,Low
```

I would like my decision tree to predict using the 12 attributes if the Target Class value is Low, Med or High based on the ViolentCrimesPerPop figure which in this example is 0.2.

My question is.... On my Test set do I just provide more un-seen examples in the same format or should I take away one of the attributes so i can see if it has learnt anything?

Comment: Hi @david-buchanan , welcome to SO. What have you done e.g. can you show us your steps please?

Comment: Are you chose the attribute in weka?

Answer (score 2):

It is a good idea to separate your dataset into three separate sets:  Training, Testing and Validation.

The training set is used to train each of the models that you are building.  This is usually checked for performance using a testing set.  As the designer continues to adjust the parameters of their model (for example, pruning options on Decision Trees and k for k-NN or Neural Network parameters), you can see how well the model is performing against the testing set.

Finally, once these parameters have been completed for your model, you can then run these against a validation set to confirm that the model did not over-fit on the testing data (due to parameter adjustments applied to the model itself).

A further discussion of these sets may be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set).

Generally, I have used a data split of 60-20-20, however it is common to use 50-25-25 as well, it really comes down to how much data you have to play with.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I agree with you, he can do a data-split and check for different combinations for maximum accuracy( if that's the measure to be taken into account.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good thing to test your classifier over your same training data, because your model has learnt, hopefully, to classify those instances correctly.

The usual set up is to train over the training dataset and then test it over a different dataset (with the same format/structure), to see how it performs.